# Bytestring types fail when installing cabal-install

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I just ran

```
apt-get install haskell-platform
cabal update
```

Now I'm trying to upgrade the cabal version using

```
cabal install cabal-install
```

But it fails and I get the following errors:

```
Resolving dependencies...
[ 1 of 81] Compiling Distribution.PackageDescription.Utils ( /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/PackageDescription/Utils.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/dist/setup/Distribution/PackageDescription/Utils.o )
[ 2 of 81] Compiling Distribution.Simple.CCompiler ( /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/Simple/CCompiler.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Simple/CCompiler.o )
[ 3 of 81] Compiling Distribution.Compat.CreatePipe ( /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/Compat/CreatePipe.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Compat/CreatePipe.o )
[ 4 of 81] Compiling Distribution.Compat.Binary.Class ( /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/Compat/Binary/Class.hs, /tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/dist/setup/Distribution/Compat/Binary/Class.o )

/tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/Compat/Binary/Class.hs:435:31:
    Couldn't match expected type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
                with actual type `B.ByteString'
    In the first argument of `putByteString', namely `bs'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putByteString bs
    In the expression:
      do { put (B.length bs);
           putByteString bs }

/tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/Compat/Binary/Class.hs:436:22:
    Couldn't match type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
                  with `B.ByteString'
    Expected type: Int -> Get B.ByteString
      Actual type: Int
                   -> Get bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `getByteString'
    In the expression: get >>= getByteString
    In an equation for `get': get = get >>= getByteString

/tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/Compat/Binary/Class.hs:445:35:
    Couldn't match expected type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
                with actual type `ByteString'
    In the first argument of `putLazyByteString', namely `bs'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putLazyByteString bs
    In the expression:
      do { put (fromIntegral (L.length bs) :: Int);
           putLazyByteString bs }

/tmp/Cabal-1.22.4.0-11586/Cabal-1.22.4.0/Distribution/Compat/Binary/Class.hs:446:22:
    Couldn't match type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString'
                  with `ByteString'
    Expected type: Int64 -> Get ByteString
      Actual type: Int64
                   -> Get bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `getLazyByteString'
    In the expression: get >>= getLazyByteString
    In an equation for `get': get = get >>= getLazyByteString
Failed to install Cabal-1.22.4.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-1.22.4.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
cabal-install-1.22.6.0 depends on Cabal-1.22.4.0 which failed to install.
```

As I said this is a completely fresh install so i don't know how I can make any changes. It seems as a version of the bytestring package is installed when I install haskell that isn't compatible with the latest cabal-install. Can I, in some way, choose which cabal i want to begin with or how do I cope with this problem?

I should note that I had a previous install of haskell-platform but i ran

```
apt-get purge haskell-platform
apt-get autoremove
```

Before i reinstalled it

Comment: I suggest you to use [hvr's](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc) GHC packages. That way you can simply `apt-get install ghc-7.10.1 cabal-install-1.22`, instead of GHC 7.6.4.

Comment: @Zeta They don't seem to be in the standard repository. Do I have to add one? In that case, how?

Comment: The instructions are on the linked site. You need to add the sources. This can be done via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hvr/ghc`, followed by `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install …`. Keep in mind that this isn't an official repository, but it's been reliable for a some time